# Error : Expected int got slice while executing Python Script

Tags: python-2.7, c#-4.0, ironpython, ptvs

I am using PTVS 2.1 in VS 2010 with Iron Python 2.7.5. I am executing `Test.py` file which has the following code :

```
import sys

def main(argv = sys.argv):
    argv1=argv[0:]
    for arg in argv1:
        print arg
```

and my C# code to call this script is:

```
var py = Python.CreateEngine();
var argv = new List<string>();
argv.Add("Item1");
argv.Add("Item2");  
argv.Add("Item3");
dynamic obj = py.ExecuteFile("Test.py");
obj.main(argv);
```

But when I try to call the Python script from the C# script, it throws an error: `expected int - got slice`, whereas when I call the same Python script from a Python project, it runs successfully. Why it is so?

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be a `List<T>`? If you used an array, it would work. .NET lists cannot accept slices (it doesn't seem to be implemented to accept them).

Comment: Thanks @ Jeff Mercado, it works perfectly. But I have another issue.I want to delete item from array.My Python code is 'del array[1]'. Now it throws error : Array[str] object does not support item deletion .